# Zerar Campo especifico no Formulario

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como não tenho muito conhecimento em javascript peço uma ajuda de de vocês...
Nesse meu código a baixo preciso resetar um campo especifico que é o campo **Pessoas** pelo ultimo campo Select

Esse formulário é uma calculadora, queria que se ao clicar em zerar no ultimo campo
ele retesa-se só o campo Pessoas corrigindo automaticamente o somatorio

preciso de uma solução simples sem alterar esse código por completo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".valores1").change(function() {
    var total = 1000;
    total += $('input[class="valores1"]:checked').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
      return tot + Number(el.value);
    }, 0);
        
        
    var e = document.getElementById("valores2");
    var itemSelecionado = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    
    var primeiroDigito = (itemSelecionado.substring(0,1));
    total=total+(primeiroDigito*100);
    
    
    
    var d = document.getElementById("valores3");
    var itemSelecionado3 = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;
    
    var primeiroDigito3 = (itemSelecionado3.substring(0,1));
    total=total+(primeiroDigito3*100);
    
    var g = document.getElementById("valores4");
    var itemSelecionado4 = g.options[g.selectedIndex].value;
    
        
    var primeiroDigito4 = (itemSelecionado4.substring(0,1));
    total=total+(primeiroDigito4/100);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    //aqui pega primeiro digito
    
    $('#total1').val(total.toFixed(2));     
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Duplica:<input type="checkbox" class="valores1" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')" name="direcao" value="1000" id="option_1"  />
Adciona:<input type="checkbox" class="valores1" name="bilingue" value="200" id="option_1"  />

<select id="valores2"   class="valores1 form-control" name="cadeirinha" >
    <option value="0">Passageiros</option>
    <option value="1">x1</option>
    <option value="2">x2</option>
    <option value="3">x3</option>
    
</select>  

<select id="valores3"   class="valores1 form-control" name="cadeirinha2" >
    <option value="0">Pessoas</option>
    <option value="1">x1</option>
    <option value="2">x2</option>
    <option value="3">x3</option>
    
</select>  

<select id="valores4"   class="valores1 form-control" name="cadeirinha2" >
    
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="0">zerar</option>
    <option value="2">x2</option>
   
    
</select>  


<input type="text" size="5"  readonly="" name="valor" id="total1" value="1000.00" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; color: green; "    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, tem só um pequeno problema no `<option value="0">zerar</option>`, que está com o mesmo `value` do `default`. Pro código que adicionei abaixo, levei em conta que esse `option` foi mudado pra 1.

Se a opção zerar for selecionada, reseto o campo pessoas e diminuo o total a partir do valor do campo de pessoas.

```
if (g.value == 1) {
  d.value = 0;
  g.value = 0;
  total = total-(primeiroDigito3*100);
  $('#total1').val(total);
}
```